Azure DevOps YAML pipeline masks URLs
I have a strange question. I have a YAML pipeline in my DevOps setup, which triggers powershell script, that is used to purge cache. Users write the URLs they want to be purged and then run the pipeline. If the caching fails, it throws an exception, which contains the user payload, and I log the errors, if there are any.
How the logging is done:
...
    $response.errors | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error]$_"
    }
...

And this is an example payload: https://iwomm-stg.example.com/pages/* .
But the problem is that if the cache invalidation fails in the pipeline, this is the result: URL/Prefix purging failed for:  ***/pages/* .
The pipeline is masking the URL (I suppose this is happening because it thinks it's a secret).
My question is: is there a way to unmask or ignore that validation so the whole URL can be seen?

Can you share more details about users how to input the URLs? How do you save the urls? Use variables or Paramters in Azure Pipeline? If possible, you can share more code about YAML Pipeline and powershell script

This usually happens when you have a secret with the same value as your example url. Secret=https://iwomm-stg.example.com
